# ViewPager in Fragment called from another Fragment Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipeview

I have an issue with my viewpager for the android app that I am working on. I have DrawerLayout that calls Fragments. One of these Fragments is the HomeFragment, which contains 2 clickable textviews. I want the HomeFragment to switch to another Fragment(ParkingTutorialFragment) which has a swipeable view. The code I am using switches to the ParkingTutorialFragment but the swipeable view does not seem to be working since nothing happens when I swipe. Below is the code for the Fragments and the adapter:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ParkingTutorialFragment extends Fragment {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int page;
    private String title;
    public static ParkingTutorialFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
        ParkingTutorialFragment parkingFragment = new ParkingTutorialFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", page);
        args.putString("someTitle", title);
        parkingFragment.setArguments(args);
        return parkingFragment;
    }

    // Store instance variables based on arguments passed
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
//      title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
    }

    // Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parking_tutorial_page, container, false);     
          return rootView;
        }

    }
```

Please Note:

```
page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
```

The above line returns null, I am not sure why if anyone can also tell me why it is not able to retrieve the key for the value "someInt" if anyone can also point that out I would greatly appreciate it

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

//Fragment for the home page
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private TypedArray tutorial_icons;
    private TextView tutorial_1;
    private ViewPager viewpager;
    FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;


    public HomeFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        viewpager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs_pager);
        adapterViewPager = new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        viewpager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
        tutorial_1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tutorial_item_1);
        tutorial_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = fragmentManager2.beginTransaction();
                ParkingTutorialFragment parkingFrag = new ParkingTutorialFragment();
                fragmentTransaction2.addToBackStack("Back");
                fragmentTransaction2.hide(HomeFragment.this);
                fragmentTransaction2.add(android.R.id.content, parkingFrag);
                fragmentTransaction2.commit();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Below is the code for the Adapter:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
            return ParkingTutorialFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1");
        case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
            return new OffersFragment();
        default:
            return ParkingTutorialFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1");
        }
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Page " + position;
    }

}
```

The flow is HomeFragment --> Press Button --> Go to ParkingTutorialFragment (supposed to contain a swipeview)
If anyone can help me achieve the desired functionality and clarify the null pointer from the .getInt method, it would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if i have understood you correctly this will do the trick.update your code inside button click.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = fragmentManager2.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction2.addToBackStack("Back");
fragmentTransaction2.hide(HomeFragment.this);
fragmentTransaction2.add(android.R.id.content, ParkingTutorialFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1"));
fragmentTransaction2.commit();
```